# Puppet Agent - cert clean vs. fqdn duplicate

Tags: puppet, certificate

I couldn't find any answer to what happened in my puppet environment, that's why I hope somebody will explain it to me here.

ENV: Foreman (Puppet CA), Puppet Master, Puppet Agent

I have an oracle vm 'server01.domain.xx' with Puppet Agent on it and it's services must be migrated to another host **with the same FQDN**.
I tried to accomplish that this way:

1. [Foreman] puppet cert clean server01.domain.xx
2. [Foreman] disassociate host (to unlink it from esx)
3. [Foreman] delete host
4. [new vm] puppet agent -t (CSR)
5. [Foreman] puppet cert sign server01.domain.xx
6. [new vm] puppet agent -t

What I didn't do is disabling puppet agent on the old host and removing ssl directory (just in case), because I thought 'puppet cert clean' should be enough even though fqdn's are the same (as well as certnames).
What's happened next? The old vm ran puppet agent and applied configuration which was already prepared for the new vm. Hopefully nothing bad happened.

So, am I missing some knowledge of how it really works? I thought that private-public key creation (4-5) makes this communication unique and same certname can't break it.

Thx in advance for any reasonable explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is unfortunately correct.
Running `puppet cert clean $certname` is not enough to lock out a still active node.
You must restart the puppet master afterwards to actually use the new CRL.

See: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/man/cert.html#ACTIONS under revoke but that applies to clean as well.

Comment: everything's "clear" ;) now, thx!